# How send list as Query param using RESTEasy client

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm trying to call service sending a list as query param using RESTEasy client:

Service:

```
@POST
@Path("/names")
public void getNames(@QueryParam("name") final List<String> names) {

}
```

Client:

```
final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl<>();
queryParams.add("name", "name1");
queryParams.add("name", "name2");
final ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
final ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(url).queryParams(queryParams);
final Builder builder = target.request();
builder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
final Response response = builder.post(Entity.form(form));
```

When I call the `/names` endpoint will have 1 element and `names.get(0) == [name1, name2]`

Comment: @Cássio Mazzochi Molin: The URI including the query parameters is usually used to identify a resource whereas the body of the request contains a representation of the resource. So in some cases it might make sense to e.g. `POST` a present to loyal customers: `/customers?minOrders=10`.

Comment: @user3784148: Which version of RESTeasy are you using? Can't reproduce it with 3.0.6.Final. Or maybe misunderstood your problem.

Comment: @lefloh I've tried to edit and accidentally removed my comment. You are completely right about the use of query parameters in `POST` requests. Thanks for providing an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved. The code that I post recently works well.

The wrong code is :

```
final List<String, String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("name1");    
list.add("name2");    
final MultivaluedMap<String, Object> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl<>();
queryParams.addAll("name", list);
final ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
final ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(url).queryParams(queryParams);;
final Builder builder = target.request();
builder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
final Response response = builder.post(Entity.form(form));
```

if I look the code of the class MultivaluedMapImpl i don't find a difference if I use "add" or "addAll" methods!!